# Override or aggregate test results in teamcity

Tags: java, testng, teamcity

I have teamcity job, with 2 steps: 
1.Execute tests.
2. Rerun failed.

We have 3 tests failed in step 1, and after rerun only 1 test is failed.

Teamcity generates report with 4 failed test instead of 1. How to override failed test results from step 1 with pass status?

**EDIT**

For example my suite looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite 1" thread-count="5" parallel="methods">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="unittest.TestNGTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Java code :

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGTest {


    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " afterMethod");
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " beforeMethod");
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] dp1() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1},
                {2}
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp1")
    public void testM1(int param) {
        Assert.assertTrue(param > 3);
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] dp2() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1},
                {2},
                {3},
                {4},
                {5},
                {6},
                {7}
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp2")
    public void testM2(int param) {
        Assert.assertFalse(param == 7);
    }

}
```

After run my code generates me rerun test suite and teamcity run this suite in second step :

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite 1" thread-count="1" parallel="methods">
    <test name="Test 1">
    <parameter name="indicies" value = "0:1"/> <-- that means that i want rerun only first and second dataprovider configuration -->
        <classes>
            <class name="unittest.TestNGTest">
            <include name = testM1/>
    </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Test 2">
<parameter name="indicies" value = "6"/> <-- that means that i want rerun only seventh dataprovider configuration -->
        <classes>
            <class name="unittest.TestNGTest">
                <include name = testM2/>  
             </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

As you can see i rerun my failed test cases with corresponding dataprovider configurations only in one thread

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to resolve this.

1. If you are using Cucumber Framework, then i would recommend that
   you use [ExtendedCucumberRunner](http://mkolisnyk.github.io/cucumber-reports/failed-tests-rerun) which has in-built support to
   re-run failed tests without increasing the tests count and you would
   not need to Rerun failed test cases separately
2. If you are using TestNG framework then implement IRetry interface to retry 
   failed test cases in same run.
3. Or as a last resort parse the results and exclude the repeated test by yourself

**EDIT:**

> so if i will rerun my case all 50 configurations would be re-run

Not true. Only those data points will run which failed in those configurations.

> I want to rerun only failed dataprovider sets (not all from each case)
>   in 1 thread.

You can control that while implementing the IRetry interface. Hence I requested to share some minimum reproducible code to demonstrate your issue.

> I've created parser which creates me new xml suite with necessary
>   indexes from dataprovider, which i can run in 1 thread.

I would suggest that you look at running the TestNG tests programmatically.

As you said that you have bulk of tests which needs to be run but not all need the retry logic, i would suggest that you club the one's needing retry logic under one suite and rest under other suite and add the IRetry listener to the retry suite.

As far as parallel execution is concerned the retry logic will follow the same route as your normal tests so if you are running in 1 thread it will run in single thread if you are running in multiple threads then it will run parallely. Basically the retry logic gets called after each test method instance.

**EDIT 2:**

TestNG.xml File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Suite 1" data-provider-thread-count="10" parallel="methods">
    <test name="Test 1">
        <classes>
            <class name="unittest.TestNGTest"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Test Class:

```
package unittest;


import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.IRetryAnalyzer;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGTest {

    public static class IRetryImplementation implements IRetryAnalyzer {
        private int retries = 3;

        @Override
        public boolean retry(ITestResult result) {
            return (retries--) > 0 && !result.isSuccess();
        }
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " afterMethod");
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod() {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " beforeMethod");
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] dp1() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1},
                {2}
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp1", retryAnalyzer = IRetryImplementation.class)
    public void testM1(int param) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " test 1");
        Assert.assertTrue(param > 1);
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] dp2() {
        return new Object[][]{
                {1},
                {2}
        };
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "dp2", retryAnalyzer = IRetryImplementation.class)
    public void testM2(int param) {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getId() + " test 2");
        Assert.assertTrue(param > 1);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
15 beforeMethod
16 beforeMethod
16 test 2
18 beforeMethod
18 test 2
17 beforeMethod
Test ignored.
16 afterMethod
16 beforeMethod
16 test 2
Test ignored.
16 afterMethod
16 beforeMethod
16 test 2
Test ignored.
16 afterMethod
16 beforeMethod
16 test 2
16 afterMethod
15 test 1
Test ignored.
17 test 1
17 afterMethod
15 afterMethod
15 beforeMethod
18 afterMethod
15 test 1
Test ignored.
15 afterMethod
15 beforeMethod
15 test 1
Test ignored.
15 afterMethod
15 beforeMethod
15 test 1
15 afterMethod
```

I have created a minimal code to demonstrate how retry works. As demonstrated in this code the failed data point runs in the same thread as in the thread which had spawned the original test method with the data-point supplied to it. Additionally as you can see it also re-runs the configuration methods as it retries to run failed method.

Comment: Thank you, I'm using testng, but i can't use IRetry because, i need run suite with different parameters. Also, where and how i can exclude repeated test result?

Comment: @AlexKvasko the IRetryAnalyzer will only rain failed tests with the arguments that were passed in the original test which means if you run the same test with another test data / parameter the IRetry will run with the supplied parameters. If you can post a minimum reproducible code in your post and show me why IRetry will not work then I can guide you better

Comment: I have test cases with about 50 dataprovider configurations, so if i will rerun my case all 50 configurations woul be reruned. And i want to rerun my tests cases in 1 thread, to maximize stability.
So i'm runnnig a lot of test cases in 5-6 threads and each testcase has from 10 to 50 dataprovider sets. I want to rerun only failed dataprovider sets (not all from each case) in 1 thread. I've created parser which creates me new xml suite with necessary indexes from dataprovider, which i can run in 1 thread.

Comment: @AlexKvasko Check my Edit

Comment: thanks for your help, but we have small misunderstanding. For example i have a 100 cases, each of case has about 50 dataprovider sets. I'm running my tests in 6 threads. Some of dataprovider configurations are failed. I want to rerun this, failed,  configurations only in  1 thread.

Comment: Okay let me start from beginning. You have 100 Test Classes each containing several '@Test' annotated methods. These test methods accept test data from '@Dataprovider' methods. Now some of the data points passed by dataprovider are failing the test methods (right?) and those data points only you wish to re-run right? and in that process you also want to run the corresponding configuration methods ('@AfterMethod' and '@BeforeMethod') along with them right?

Comment: Yes, and i want to rerun those data point in 1 thread. My main run goes in 5-6 threads.

Comment: @AlexKvasko Please check my EDIT 2 and that should resolve your doubt.

Comment: Please check my EDIT